# drupalgap webapp setup into subdomain

Tags: javascript

My main website is www.example.com. And I have 3 types content like: book,food,tutorial.

Now I want to serve all Book item from **book.example.com** subdomain. Is it possible to develop it with drupalgap using example.com node/content and same authentication?

[After installing drupalgap module, I download web-app drupalgap zip file, and set it to **book.example.com** but, CORS problem detected.]

anyone help please.

Answer (score 1):

solving cors problem I just add configuration into my .conf file.

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply need to set the cookie domain in your settings.php to "example.com".

Comment: Hi @Karel, Thanx for your answer. I have changed but not working... :(